# Modular arithmetic question mod y^2

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In a test a question has asked us to find [sin(2(x+y))] (modulo y^2), however I haven't been able to find it. The answers say that its equal to sin(2x)+y*cos(2x) but I haven't been able to get this result so could anybody help?
Heres a picture of the question
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSCHN.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like someone may have been thinking about the angle-sum formulas, which give us
$$
\sin(2(x+y)) = \cos(2y) \sin(2x) + \sin(2y) \cos(2x).
$$

It's not clear how they thought they could get 
$\sin(2(x+y)) \equiv \sin(2x)+y\cos(2x) \pmod{y^2}$
from this, however.
Perhaps they were thinking of the series expansions of the
sine and cosine functions,
but the alleged answer seems simply wrong.
Consider the example
\begin{align}
x &= 0 \\
y &= 10 \\
y^2 &= 100 \\
\sin(2(x+y)) &= \sin(20) \approx 0.91294525072 \\
\sin(2x)+y\cos(2x) &= 0 + y \cdot 1 = 10
\end{align}
It's difficult for me to see how $0.91294525072$ and $10$ 
could be considered congruent modulo $100$,
even setting aside what it means for $\sin(20)$ to be congruent
to *anything* modulo $100$.

Are you supposed to be using some special definitions of
$\sin$ and $\cos$?
If so, we need to know those function definitions in order to
correctly find the answer to the question.

Comment: Hey David, we were told to use series expansions for trigonometric functions and then take modulo y^2 of the series; which meant that sin(y) modulo y^2 is equal to the expansion on sin(y) modulo y^2, for example. Hope this helps.

Comment: It's still unclear how the functions are meant to be defined. For example, the Taylor series for $\sin t$ has a term $t^3/6$. If $y$ is divisible by $3$ then $6n \equiv 1\pmod{y^2}$ has no solution, so what's $\sin(2x)$ then? I think you should ask to see exact values worked out for a few examples such as $\sin(2x)\pmod{y^2}$ when $x=1$ and $y=3$.

Comment: We don't need the exact values, we were told to take divide the series expansion of sin and cos by y^2, for which you can ignore coefficients, and then substitute this value in for sin and cos respectively.

Comment: With all due respect to your instructor, I don't believe it. In order to manipulate a series like that, the terms have to be defined. If we interpret the terms as rational numbers, you can't assume that whenever $y^2$ appears in the numerator of a term, that term is divisible by $y^2$. That is simply not true. If we interpret the terms as being computed using multiplication and division modulo $y^2$, we get a lot of terms that do not have any value because they involve division by impossible amounts. It's not legitimate to say $(0\times k)/0 = k$ because you can "cancel" the zeros.

Comment: I'm not saying the equation cannot be justified--just that in order to justify it, the things in it _have to be defined_ in a sound way. If your instructor can't produce values of the functions for simple inputs then the things they're writing aren't functions.

Comment: Ok then, I'll have to ask my lecturer about it but thanks for your help anyways